# 4-bit adder subtractor Verilog code errors

Tags: verilog, test-bench

I am trying to do a 4-bit adder subtractor in Verilog code, but there is some kind of problem in my code that I couldn't figure out. I'm not sure if the testbench or the Verilog is wrong. Can someone please help me with it? Also, when I try to simulate it, it gives Loading Errors.

My Verilog code:

```
module addsubparameter (A, B, OP, C_out, Sum);

input A,B;
input OP;
output C_out;
output Sum;

wire C_out, Sum;
reg assigning;

always@(OP)
begin
if (OP == 0)
    assigning = A + B + OP;
else
    assigning = A + (~B + 1) + OP;
end

assign {C_out, Sum} = assigning;

endmodule

module adder (a, b, op, cout, sum);
parameter size = 4 ;

input [3:0] a, b;
output [3:0] sum;

input op;
output cout;
wire [2:0] c;

genvar i;
generate
for (i = 0; i < size; i = i + 1) begin: adder
    if (i == 0)
        addsubparameter (a[i], b[i], op, sum[i], c[i]);
    else if (i == 3) 
        addsubparameter (a[i], b[i], c[i-1], cout, sum[i]);
    else
        addsubparameter (a[i], b[i], c[i-1], sum[i], c[i]);
end 
endgenerate
endmodule
```

And this is my testbench:

```
module addsub_tb();

reg [3:0] a;
reg [3:0] b;
reg op;

wire [3:0] sum;
wire cout;

adder DUT (a,b,op,sum,cout);

initial begin
    a = 4'b1010; b = 4'b1100; op = 1'b0; #100;
    a = 4'b1111; b = 4'b1011; op = 1'b1; #100;
    a = 4'b1010; b = 4'b1010; op = 1'b0; #100;
end
      
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your simulator should generate error and/or warning messages because you have syntax errors.  If it does not, sign up for a free account on edaplayground, where you will have access to multiple simulators which will produce helpful messages.

You need to add instance names.  For example, I added `i0` in the line below:

```
    addsubparameter i0 (a[i], b[i], op, sum[i], c[i]);
```

You have port connection width mismatches, and these indicate connection errors.  This is a common type of error when you use connections by position.  You mistakenly connected the `sum` signal to the `cout` port, and vice versa.  You should use connections by name instead.  For example, change:

```
adder DUT (a,b,op,sum,cout);
```

to:

```
adder dut (
    .a     (a),
    .b     (b),
    .op    (op),
    .cout  (cout),
    .sum   (sum)
);
```

Use this coding style for all your instances.

You won't get a simulation warning, but you might get a synthesis warnings about an incomplete sensitivity list.  Change:

```
always@(OP)
```

to:

```
always @*
```